# how to rebuild/update graspit-simulator package

Tags: ros, makefile, rosmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I downloaded graspit simulator from debs.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-graspit-simulator
```

It runs well.

Now I changed part of the source code and want to rebuild the package `graspit`. I added the patch file "new.patch" to the [Makefile.graspit.tarball in the root directory of graspit package](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/graspit_simulator/tags/diamondback/graspit/Makefile.graspit.tarball):

> TARBALL_PATCH=graspit/graspit_project.patch graspit/graspit_dbase.patch

to

> TARBALL_PATCH=graspit/graspit_project.patch graspit/graspit_dbase.patch graspit/new.patch

I thought i can just rebuild the package by typing rosmake graspit. But it didn't build saying there is a ROS_BUILD there. So I removed this file to allow rosmake to take effect. But then it goes:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> graspit [ make ]                                       
[ rosmake ] All 2 linesgraspit: 0.0 sec ]            [ 1 Active 45/46 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package graspit written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110820-164256/graspit/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< graspit [FAIL] [ 0.05 seconds ]
```

Can someone help me out with this and tell me what's the standard procedure of patching and rebuilding a ROS package? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10962/how-to-rebuild/update-graspit-simulator-package/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the following;

```
rosmake --pre-clean
```

usually does the job for the packages in which `ROS_NO_BUILD` tag exists, which is most of the 'big' packages. The permission error is just because the package exists somewhere like `/opt/.../` which is protected.

To patch the package, I would recommend checking it out onto a folder where permissions are not an issue like around the `$HOME` or so, then add that path to the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` like so;

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:<put the path here>
```

or do it the `bashrc` way.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-21**:
another question, still in the /opt/... path, I tried `sudo rosmake`, it said cannot find rospack command. So does that mean 'sudo' doesn't apply to all the commands?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo rosmake doesn't work because you're not getting your environment variables.  You can see that by doing 'printenv | grep ROS' and then 'sudo printenv | grep ROS'.  If you do su - to switch to root, then source your usual ~/.bashrc (or whatever file you use to set your ROS_ROOT and all that), you should be able to use rospack commands as root.  I would not recommend trying to re-build inside debs, though.  You should always overlay if you want to change and re-build.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-24**:
thanks